# Postgres 9.2 under FreeBSD 8.4 - How do I find the databases & tables?

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to create an osm tileserver and am at the point where i've created the database to hold the output of osm2pgsql.  But I can find neither the database (map_data) nor, of course, its tables.  I need to softlink (ln -s) the tables to at least one other spindle, which has nearly a full TB of space open.  I look in pgsql/data/base and see a lot of subtrees with numeric names.  Presumably one of them is my map_data, but I can't find a name:number mapping table.

I'm used to MariaDB/MySQL, which seems much more straightforward to me.

Comment: Just FYI, the name/number mapping is `SELECT pg_relation_filepath('relname_or_oid')` and is done via `pg_class`'s. `relfilenode` attribute, plus the tablespace path. Never, ever, *EVER* mess with files in the database directory directly, though.

Answer (score 3):

Don't mess with the data files in the filesystem it's a sure way to get your database corrupted.

You can achieve what you want, by creating a tablespace and then move the table to the new tablespace:

```
create tablespace big_one LOCATION '/path/to/other/spindle';
alter table map_data set tablespace big_one;
commit;
```

<sup>Btw: MySQL isn't "*more straightforward*" - it's just different. And I could list several things that are much more "straightforward" in Postgres than in MySQL</sup>

Comment: ... and remember, it's not safe to put a tablespace of "less important" stuff on a less reliable disk. Unfortunately the way Pg's tablespace support is designed, your database is just as stuffed if an unimportant tablespace goes away unexpectedly.

Comment: I'm aware that to say thanks in comments violates convention here but not saying thanks at all doesn't work for me, so: Thank you, horse and Craig.  I don't have enough mojo yet to uptick your responses, so this is the best I can do.